# How to set a minimal Ruby page on a webserver that can add / edit / delete records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra

I am trying to add a page on dreamhost.com to display

```
record = Record.find(params[:id])   # such as Record.find(1)
print record.content                # to show content of this record
```

and that's it... probably using sqlite or mysql, and want to have the ability to add a record, similar to Ruby on Rails's scaffold.

If using Ruby on Rails, it is probably too big for such a simple purpose, but if I use Sinatra, then it looks like I have to start it on a port (and can't start it on port 80 because it is the dreamhost.com's port)

Can Sinatra or any tool or framework fit this purpose?

Answer (score 2):

#### Go with Rails

---

Dreamhost offers Rails already installed and at no extra cost.  And knowing Rails will certainly be more useful to you in the future than knowing Sinatra.

So, I don't see the benefit in Sinatra unless you are hosting the server.

Since Rails is a *framework*, it will give you a basic application easily, despite it's massive internal complexity.

I know this doesn't exactly answer the question, sorry about that, but on a shared-hosting site you will have limited opportunity to fiddle with the configuration. It's easier in this case to go with Rails.

Comment: but how many Rails can it support?  For example, if I have another page, then start yet another Rails server?  Are the servers quite big... taking up tens of MB in RAM?

Comment: Dreamhost likely uses Passenger which will kill off the idle Rails instances and restart them when needed. It will be a slam dunk for you to do what you are looking for w/ Rails.

Comment: Note that if Dreamhost is running Passenger, they probably also support Rack applications, of which Sinatra is one, if you really want to run Sinatra. See [this post](http://www.gittr.com/index.php/archive/deploying-rack-apps-on-dreamhost-via-passenger-including-sinatra/) and Google (I searched for "dreamhost ruby rack").

Answer (score 1):

Rails isn't really that heavyweight. Unless you need your "app" to be very high performance, Rails is probably a good solution that'll let you have this up in a matter of a couple hours.

That said, I'm sure Dreamhost has a way for you to run a Sinatra app within Phusion.

Comment: please see note under "DigitalRoss"... but if I have 8 pages like that, then run 8 Rails server... probably not so practical... or I can run 1 Rails server to server these all 8 pages, but what if I want to start another Rails project... then start another Rails server?

Comment: Ruby isn't PHP — Rails operates as a daemon, staying in memory and serving requests as they come in. One instance can serve a single request at a time, but with a lightweight application it can take as little as about 8-10ms for a request to complete, yielding well over 100 requests per second.

Comment: So even running it on heroku is practical?

Comment: Extremely. I don't see why you wouldn't think so.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why nobody mentioned [Padrino](http://www.padrinorb.com/) yet. It is lightweight and provides you with a simple [admin interface](http://www.padrinorb.com/guides/padrino-admin)!

Comment: +1 from me, OP's question sounds exactly like the kind of app I usually recommend Padrino for.